# How Nodatime handles the changes in the IANA timezone?

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

I have started using NodaTime. If there are any changes in the IANA time zone or for example they add a new time zone. Then will we need to upgrade the nodatime library or will it handle it?

Comment: https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/tzdb

Comment: @DanielA.White Please explain `InZoneLeniently` with example

Comment: I've removed the second half of the post, as it was entirely unrelated to the first. Each Stack Overflow post is meant to ask *one* question. (I'm sure I've mentioned that to you in the past...)

Comment: If you need to ask multiple questions (after *really* doing your research, e.g. reading the user guide thoroughly, including https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/concepts) then ask in multiple posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noda Time won't change its default time zone database automatically. (That would be really disruptive, would require a network connection etc.)

However:

- Shortly after a new version is announced to the IANA database, a new NuGet package is released for each minor version we're currently still updating. In most cases this is sufficient - an app which updates the dependency reasonably frequently is likely to "see" the new data far more quickly than apps using operating system default time zone information.
- A new nzd file is made available on nodatime.org
- The link in https://nodatime.org/tzdb/latest.txt is updated

The latter two bullets allow your application to dynamically download the latest database and use it as an input for `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource`. See [the documentation](https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/tzdb) for sample source code (assuming you've already downloaded the database).