# What is equivalent of TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime in NodaTime?

Tags: nodatime

I want to use the NodaTime library to convert the date from one timezone to another like this.

```
string fromSystemTimeZoneId = "GMT Standard Time";
string toSystemTimeZoneId = "Central Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo fromTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(fromSystemTimeZoneId);
TimeZoneInfo toTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(toSystemTimeZoneId);
var convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(inputDateTime, fromTimeZone, toTimeZone);
```

The above code works perfectly fine for me, But now I want to use IANA standard time zone (like Europe/London and America/Chicago) in place of windows OS-provided time zone ids.

I am using .net 4.7.2 and cannot upgrade the framework due to some limitations.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39220954/6527049) answer, But I am looking for simple few lines of code nothing complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I am looking for simple few lines of code nothing complicated.

But you're trying to *do* something complicated. Noda Time makes everything explicit, which means it's clear exactly what's going on - at the cost of being a little more verbose.

`DateTime` has no concept of a time zone itself (other than for the special cases where the `Kind` is `Utc` or `Local`). So `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` has to:

- Consider what instant in time is represented by `inputDateTime` in `fromTimeZone`
- Work out what that instant in time looks like in `outputDateTime`

In Noda Time, those are are two separate operations, if you want to start and end with a `LocalDateTime`:

```cs
LocalDateTime inputDateTime = ...;
DateTimeZone fromTimeZone = ...;
DateTimeZone toTimeZone = ...;

// There are options for how this conversion is performed, as noted in other questions
ZonedDateTime inputDateTimeInFromTimeZone = inputDateTime.InZoneLeniently(fromTimeZone);
// This conversion is always unambiguous, because ZonedDateTime unambiguously
// refers to a single instant in time
ZonedDateTime inputDateTimeInToTimeZone = inputDateTimeInFromTimeZone.WithZone(toTimeZone);

LocalDateTime localPart = inputDateTimeInToTimeZone.LocalDateTime;
```

So that's basically the equivalent conversion - but you need to be explicit about how you want to handle skipped/ambiguous inputs. If you want everything in your app to use the same conversion, you can wrap that in a method that looks just like `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`. But why not just keep things in a `ZonedDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime` to start with? Then you don't get into the ambiguous position - other than potentially when converting user input (which is *entirely* separate from converting from one time zone to another).

Comment: I get the date as string `yyMMddHHmm` from different clients and I get to know the time zone from the client id. I want to store this date in DB in CST (America/Chicago). I may save this date in a different time zone tomorrow (just keep that in mind)

Comment: @viveknuna: It's worth trying to be *really precise*. You don't get a *date*, you get a *date/time*. A date wouldn't have a time portion. So again, you should ask yourself: what do you want to do if the value you receive is skipped or ambiguous in the client's time zone? You need to keep reading this answer until you understand why there are really two conversions here - one to understand the "local" value in the client's time zone, and one to convert the result of that into the Chicago time zone. Once you've understood that, everything else is likely to make more sense.

Comment: @viveknuna: Also note that CST isn't the Chicago time zone. Chicago varies between CST and CDT.